# How can I add my connector to the Joomla! extensions page?

Tags: translation

The company I work for has created a plugin/connector for Joomla!, and we'd like to be able to make it available for Joomla! users.  The main purpose of the plugin is to automate the processing of localization content. We're not necessarily providing the translations ourselves, it's more of a middleware that allows for more flexibility on the side of the actual translation source. It could be an LSP, MT Engine, or even a CAT tool in some cases like Phrase, memoQ, RWS, etc.

A paid subscription to our service is required to enable access to the platform, but from there all available connectors can be used, and we're adding more all the time.

Maybe this isn't the best place to ask this question but I was hoping to speak with someone about getting the app we made on the app store, and we've done the same in our app store with the Joomla! connector we made, this way anyone already using our software can also see Joomla! as an available data source for translation content.

There's also more information on what we've built in our public help page here: https://help.locale.to/en/collections/5822391-joomla in case it's at all helpful.

Thanks!
-Joe

Comment: Are you asking about listing your project on Joomla! Extensions Directory (JED)?